# Best practice when validating input in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, validation

When is it better to use an inputParser than assert when validating input in a MATLAB function. Or is there other, even better tools available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally found using the inputParser unnecessarily complicated.  For Matlab, there are always 3 things to check - Presence, Type and Range/Values.  Sometimes you have to assign defaults.  Here is some sample code, very typical of my error checking:  `dayofWeek` is the argument, 3rd in the function.  (Extra comments added.)  Most of this code predates the existence of `assert()` in Matlab.  I use asserts in my later code instead of the `if ... error()` constructs.

```
%Presence
if nargin < 3 || isempty(dayOfWeek);
    dayOfWeek = '';
end

%Type
if ~ischar(dayOfWeek);
    error(MsgId.ARGUMENT_E, 'dayOfWeek must be a char array.');
end

%Range
days = { 'Fri' 'Sat' 'Sun' 'Mon' 'Tue' 'Wed' 'Thu' };

%A utility function I wrote that checks the value against the first arg, 
%and in this case, assigns the first element if argument is empty, or bad.
dayOfWeek = StringUtil.checkEnum(days, dayOfWeek, 'assign');

%if I'm this far, I know I have a good, valid value for dayOfWeek
```